# Scala macro inspect tree for anonymous function

Tags: scala, abstract-syntax-tree, anonymous-function, scala-macros, inspection

I'm just getting started with macros and feel like I'm missing something really painfully obvious...

I want to inspect the AST for an anonymous lambda function passed to my macro, ultimately I want to do things to it, but I've fallen at the first hurdle.

My code looks like this;

```
object Test extends App {
  doIt(() => "bar")

  def doIt(f: () => String) = {
    Builder.build(f)
  }
}

object Builder {
  def build[R](func: () => R): String = macro builder_impl[R]

  def builder_impl[R](c: blackbox.Context)(func: c.Expr[() => R]): c.Expr[String] = {
    import c.universe._

    println(showRaw(func))

    reify {
      println("hello yeah")
      "foo"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm expecting showRaw to print something like;

```
Expr(Function(List(), Literal(Constant("bar"))))
```

However, instead I get;

```
Expr(Ident(TermName("f")))
```

I can get what I want by defining my anonymous function at the call site to Builder.build like this;

```
Builder.build(() => "bar")
```

However, this doesn't help me do what I need.

Can some please explain what I'm misunderstanding, how can I achieve my goal?

Also, is there some awesome Scala macro cookbook that I should read?

Regards,

Ryan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only get AST of what you passed to a macro (in this case the only macro involved is `build`, and you call it with argument `f`, so you get the AST of `f`). So if you want to get the AST of `() => "bar"` in `doIt(() => "bar")`, `doIt` itself must be a macro.

Comment: Hey, what does it mean for you that doIt must be a macro ?

Comment: @alifirat That it should be defined as `def doIt(f: () => String) = macro ...` (note that the question is about Scala 2).

Comment: And what will be the goal of this function ? Return the AST of the lambda ? Because I have a similar issue and I had trouble to fix it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71444782/get-an-scala-matcherror-f-of-class-scala-reflect-internal-treesident-when-pr

Comment: You would need to ask the question's author for the goal, not me :) It just says "I want to inspect the AST for an anonymous lambda function passed to my macro, ultimately I want to do things to it" but the answer doesn't depend on it.