# Get an scala.MatchError: f (of class scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Ident) when providing a lambda assigned to a val

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I'm kind like discovering the macros for an use case in which I tried to extract the lambda arg names from a function. To do so, I've defined this class (let's say in a module A):

```
object MacroTest {

  def getLambdaArgNames[A, B](f: A => B): String = macro getLambdaArgNamesImpl[A, B]

  def getLambdaArgNamesImpl[A, B](c: Context)(f: c.Expr[A => B]): c.Expr[String] = {
    import c.universe._
    val Function(args, body) = f.tree
    val names = args.map(_.name)
    val argNames = names.mkString(", ")
    val constant = Literal(Constant(argNames))
    c.Expr[String](q"$constant")
  }
```

Now in another module, I'm trying to write an unit like to check the names of the argument named passed to a lambda :

```
class TestSomething extends AnyFreeSpec with Matchers {
  "test" in {
    val f = (e1: Expr[Int]) => e1 === 3
    val argNames = MacroTest.getLambdaArgNames(f)
    println(argNames)
    assert(argNames === "e1")
  }
}
```

But this code doesn't compile because of :
`scala.MatchError: f (of class scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Ident)`

But if I pass directly the lambda to the function like `MacroTest.getLambdaArgNames((e1: Expr[Int]) => e1 === 3)` it's working so I'm pretty lost about the reason that makes the code not compiling.

Any possible solution to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

It's the same issue as in [Scala macro inspect tree for anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36344046/scala-macro-inspect-tree-for-anonymous-function?noredirect=1&lq=1), where you commented: you really do need to pass the lambda itself to the macro, as you say

> if I pass directly the lambda to the function like `MacroTest.getLambdaArgNames((e1: Expr[Int]) => e1 === 3)` it's working

When you write `MacroTest.getLambdaArgNames(f)`, the AST argument (`f: c.Expr[A => B]` in `getLambdaArgNamesImpl`) just stores the identifier `f` and the lambda's AST isn't stored anywhere.

Alternately, you can store the AST for the lambda in `f`, not the the lambda itself:

```
val f = q"(e1: Expr[Int]) => e1 === 3"
```

[in Scala 2](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/intro.html),

```
val f = '{ (e1: Expr[Int]) => e1 === 3 }
```

[in Scala 3](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/macros/quotes.html), and then make `getLambdaArgNames` a normal function.

Comment: So if I understand well, there is no way to get the source of the lambda directly from the lambda itself ?

Comment: Yes. The information is simply not stored anywhere after compilation (there are languages which do, e.g. JavaScript, but not Scala). _Maybe_ for this specific case you could use reflection instead, but it depends on compilation details which I don't know at the moment and could easily change between Scala versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try approach with `Traverser`

```scala
def getLambdaArgNamesImpl[A, B](c: blackbox.Context)(f: c.Expr[A => B]): c.Expr[String] = {
  import c.universe._

  val arguments = f.tree match {
    case Function(args, body) => args

    case _ =>
      var rhs: Option[Tree] = None

      val traverser = new Traverser {
        override def traverse(tree: Tree): Unit = {
          tree match {
            case q"$_ val f: $_ = $expr"
              if tree.symbol == f.tree.symbol ||
                (tree.symbol.isTerm && tree.symbol.asTerm.getter == f.tree.symbol) =>
              rhs = Some(expr)
            case _ => super.traverse(tree)
          }
        }
      }

      c.enclosingRun.units.foreach(unit => traverser.traverse(unit.body))

      rhs match {
        case Some(Function(args, body)) => args
        case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "can't find definition of val f")
      }
  }

  val names = arguments.map(_.name)
  val argNames = names.mkString(", ")
  val constant = Literal(Constant(argNames))
  c.Expr[String](q"$constant")
}
```

Case `tree.symbol == f.tree.symbol` matches when `f` is a local variable

```
class TestSomething extends AnyFreeSpec with Matchers {
  "test" in {
    val f = (e1: Expr[Int]) => e1 === 3
    ...
```

Case `tree.symbol.asTerm.getter == f.tree.symbol` matches when `f` is a field in a class

```
class TestSomething extends AnyFreeSpec with Matchers {
  val f = (e1: Expr[Int]) => e1 === 3
  "test" in {
    ...
```

[Def Macro, pass parameter from a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63132189)

[Creating a method definition tree from a method symbol and a body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767582)

[Scala macro how to convert a MethodSymbol to DefDef with parameter default values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60806283)

[How to get the runtime value of parameter passed to a Scala macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59387459)

Comment: And it’s still working if you provide the lambda directly to a function ?

Comment: @alifirat You're right. It wasn't. Fixed.

Comment: @alifirat Surely, if you do something more complicated than single assignment e.g. like `val f0 = (e1: Expr[Int]) => e1 === 3; val f = f0; getLambdaArgNames(f)` then it will break again.